# opensaml::FatalProfileException A logout message from your identity provider has blocked your login attempt

Tags: shibboleth

I am testing SLO functionality of Shibboleth SP combined with WSO2 Identity Server as IDP. The exception from title is shown if I try to login to a service very soon after service provider has received Logout message through the back-channel (more details below).

**My question is, can this behaviour of Shibboleth Service Provider be turned off by configuration?** This resembles something that can be controlled by SecutiryPolicy rules, but I failed to find which.

---

---

Testing scenario:
Configured an instance of WSO2IS ver. 5.1.0, and two instances of Shibboleth SP ver. 2.6 (Apache 2.4). WSO2IS is configured to use /SLO/POST binding point of Shibboleth's for the Single Logout.

1. Access a secure location of SP1, browser is redirected to IDP login, after a successful login browser is redirected back to SP1 and secure page is shown.
2. Access a secure location of SP2, browser is redirected to IDP which redirects id back right away (since user is logged in) and secure page of SP2 is shown.
3. Logout from SP1. IDP through a back-channel sends a LogoutRequest to SP2.
4. Try to access (refresh) secure page of SP2 again. Browser is redirected to the IDP login page.

(*Up to this point everything works as expected - after successful SLO SP2 must login again in order to access protected resource*).

5. Enter user credentials, login is completed (judging by the saml messages exchanged), but instead of SP2 page - Shibboleth exception page is shown.

I will add that looking at log files does not reveal much about this problem to me. WSO2IS log shows no errors.

```
shibd.log of SP2
(after first login to SP2)
INFO Shibboleth.SessionCache [5]: new session created: ID (_1cf4bfa247ec917f987d485e32aa102c) IdP (wso2is) Protocol(urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol) Address (147...)

(after logout from SP1)
INFO Shibboleth.Logout.SAML2 [1]: processing front channel logout request with no active session
INFO Shibboleth.SessionCache [1]: request to logout sessions from (wso2is) for (user@carbon.super)
INFO Shibboleth.SessionCache [9]: removed session (_1cf4bfa247ec917f987d485e32aa102c)
INFO Shibboleth.Logout.SAML2 [9]: client's session isn't available, skipping front-channel notifications

(than after second login, event tho SAML messages are exchanged with the IDP the same way as the first time, and with no errors, new session is not created)
(at that point shibboleth-www/native.log shows:)

DEBUG Shibboleth.Listener [10379] shib_handler: sending message (default/SAML2/POST)
DEBUG Shibboleth.Listener [10379] shib_handler: send completed, reading response message
ERROR Shibboleth.Listener [10379] shib_handler: remoted message returned an error: A logout message from your identity provider has blocked your login attempt.
ERROR Shibboleth.Apache [10379] shib_handler: A logout message from your identity provider has blocked your login attempt.
```

- NOTE: ***I must add that if I try to access SP2 page again after some time has passed, it is shown normally (there is a new SamlRequest/Response exchange with IDP). Even knownig the length of this timeout will be helpful to me***.